# How To Delete OneDrive For Business Sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, onedrive-for-business

Some of our users have been accessing OneDrive for Business sites in O365 but a decision has been made to disable OneDrive for Business.  The settings have been changed to disable OneDrive for Business but those existing sites still exist and users can access them.

How can we remove the OneDrive for Business sites using PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a `Remove-SPOSite -identity https://tenant.sharepoint.com/personal/user_domain_com` for each of the sites you want to delete.

Comment: What are the implications to doing this (other than the site is deleted)?  I see on some other blogs that the sites cannot be recreated later.

Comment: TBH, idk, I've never had the need to delete one. The only ones that get deleted are done automatically when users are offboarded/license removed. If you are hesitant in deleting them, you could always just remove their SCA access to them and add them back at a later date.